# How can I use JQuery to have different content populate a space from navigation click?

Tags: jquery, html, navigation, onclick

I don't know JQuery but am looking to create a box that populates with different content based on clicks from a navigation bar above.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is far too broad a question. Read some jQuery tutorials, work through some exercises, study code that does similar things on existing sites, and take a stab at it. People are happy to help you if you run into trouble.

Comment: Hey everyone - Sorry for the general question. Was just looking for a starting spot. Thanks for all of the help in knowing what to read up on!

Comment: If you found the information useful, it would be appreciated if you could the helpful answers a "+1" (and possibly accept an answer by clicking the checkmark).

Comment: @steve - I would but cannot. Because of the -1's from this comment my score is not high enough to be able to +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, you should read up on the basic concepts of jQuery, in particular the jQuery [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)/[text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) functions.

In the most basic form, you would use it something like this:

```
$('#myNavLink').click(function(){
  $('#myContentArea').text("This is the new content text");
});
```

Comment: After messing with it a little - this was just what i needed. Here is what I came up with - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/t2x9G/) - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment on the question, this question is too broad and I expect it will get closed by the community. But I thought I'd offer a couple of pointers:

1. You can trigger a function call when an element is clicked by having jQuery hook up a `click` handler on that element. You need to be able to tell jQuery which element you're talking about, which you can do with any CSS selector. You might use an `id` (although `id`s are not necessarily the best choice in general). For example:

   ```
   $("#foo").click(function() {
       alert("Hi there");
   });
   ```

   ...will hook up that function to the `click` event on the element with the `id` `"foo"`.
2. You can load content into an element using the `html` function (for content you specify in a string in the code) or the `load` function (for content you load from your server on-demand), again by having jQuery look up the element, and then acting on it:

   ```
   $("#foo").html("New content");

   $("#foo").load("/path/to/new/content/on/server");
   ```

The [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com) are a good starting point, and there are any number of online tutorials and blogs. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question and has answers all over the internet; however, to get you started you will want to check out the following syntax:

```
var value = '<p>Here is my new content that came from my database, fetched using Ajax & jQuery!</p>';
$('#mydiv').html(value);
```

Mind you that the code above is very destructive meaning that it will completely replace all content.

Good luck!